# Alterar um valor de uma propriedade após o clique aspnet

Tags: c#, asp

Tenho todo o CRUD feito, mas gostaria que quando clicar no botão *"aprovar"* na minha View onde está listando os dados Cadastrados, alterasse apenas a propriedade **Situacao**. Coloquei por padrão, para ela receber sempre "Pendente" na **ActionResult Cadastro**.

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Cadastrar(Reserva reserva)
    {

        reserva.Situacao = "Pendente";


        _RRE.Inserir(reserva);

        return RedirectToAction("Index");

    }
```

Até ai tudo beleza.
E na Minha Index coloquei coloquei um botão que manda para minha **ActionResult Aprovado**. A ideia seria usar a mesma lógica, colocando para minha propriedade **Situacao** receber "Aprovado" quando a **ActionResult Aprovado** fosse chamada, mas não dar certo. Os outros valores vem nulos.

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Aprovado(Reserva item)
    {
        item.Situacao = "Aprovado";

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // TODO: Add update logic here
            _RRE.Alterar(item);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        else
        {
            return View(item);
        }
    }
```

View Index
[image: Listagem]

Resultado a após o click no botão "Aprovar"
[image: View ActionResult Aprovado]

Veja que ele recebeu "Aprovado", mas os outros valores vieram nulos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ele está retornando para o form com os valores nulos porque o ModelState da sua view está inválido nesse caso ele retorna para a view do formulário e só redireciona para index novamente se ela estiver válida.

Veja em seu código o trecho em que você determina esse comportamento:

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    // TODO: Add update logic here
    _RRE.Alterar(item);
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
else
{
    return View(item);
}
```

Isso acontece porque o post que está fazendo ao clicar no botão Aprovar não está submetendo uma representação válida do objeto que a action está esperando na controller.

Nesse caso ou você cria outra ViewModel específica para a ação ou muda a sua condição, garantindo que está recebendo ao menos o atributo `Id_Usuario` e verifique a validade da operação por ele.

Comment: Leandro, mas na criação da Action, estou fazendo correto ?